# erlang: to controlling_process(), or not to controlling_process()

Tags: sockets, erlang, gen-tcp

Consider the following erlang code of a simple echo server:

Echo listener:

```
-module(echo_listener).
-export([start_link/1]).

-define(TCP_OPTIONS, [binary, {packet, 0}, {reuseaddr, true},
                        {keepalive, true}, {backlog, 30}, {active, false}]).

start_link(ListenPort) ->
    {ok, ListenSocket} = gen_tcp:listen(ListenPort, ?TCP_OPTIONS),
    accept_loop(ListenSocket).

accept_loop(ListenSocket) ->
    {ok, ClientSocket} = gen_tcp:accept(ListenSocket),
    Pid = spawn(echo_worker, usher, [ClientSocket]),
    gen_tcp:controlling_process(ClientSocket, Pid),
    accept_loop(ListenSocket).
```

Echo worker:

```
-module(echo_worker).
-export([echo/1]).

echo(ClientSocket) ->
    case gen_tcp:recv(ClientSocket, 0) of
        {ok, Data} ->
            gen_tcp:send(ClientSocket, Data),
            echo(ClientSocket);
        {error, closed} ->
            ok
    end.
```

Whenever a client socket is accepted, the echo server spawns a echo worker and pass the client socket directly as a function parameter.  In the code there is controller_process(), but I have tried the code without calling controlling_process(), it also works.

What is the real purpose of controlling_process()?  When is it needed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erlang documentation says about gen_tcp:controlling_process/1:

> Assigns a new controlling process Pid to Socket. The controlling process is the process which receives messages from the socket. If 
>   called by any other process than the current controlling process,
>   {error, not_owner} is returned.

You created listen socket with option {active, false} and you read the socket synchronously with gen_tcp:recv/2 so your code will work even without calling of gen_tcp:controlling_process/1. However if you want to receive data asynchronously you must create listen socket with option {active, true}. In that case owner of accepted connection will receive messages about incoming data. So if you dont call gen_tcp:controlling_process/1 these messages will be sent to listener process instead of worker.

Comment: One thing to note: Only the process in which the client socket was obtained can invoke this method :gen_tcp.controlling_process(sock, pid). Else arises an error regarding ownership.